# Как определить название таблицы в модели Eloquent Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Название таблицы для модели Order, например Order_fgeg234uib, хранится в таблице Users в колонке orders. Ниже приведенный код не позволяет определить таблицу и соответствующую модель для аутентифицированного пользователя:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
  protected $table;

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->table = auth()->user()->orders;
  }
}
```

выдает при обращении по роуту ошибку как раз в этом файле в строке конструктора, хотя пользователь аутентифицирован и его объект существует(я проверял):

```
Trying to get property 'orders' of non-object
```

Подскажите, может не в модели, а в контроллере или репозитории, например, нужно определить название таблицы таким образом и как? при определении в конструкторе контроллера выходит аналогичная ошибка.

Comment: Не понял, это получается у вас таблицы динамически создаются? Зачем?

Comment: Да, для каждого пользователя своя таблица. Это необходимо

Comment: Капец ты намучаешься с таким подходом. Рассмотри вариант multi-tenant проекта, для Лары даже пакет есть https://laravel-tenancy.com

Comment: А в чем заключаются мучения? В том что много таблиц будет?